# Prove ${\gcd\left({\rm lcm}\left(m_1,m_2\right),m_3\right){\rm lcm}\left(m_1,m_2,m_3\right)} = {\rm lcm}(m_1,m_2)m_3$

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

Is it possible to proof: when $gcd\left(m_1,m_2,m_3\right)=1$, then $\frac{lcm\left(m_1,m_2\right)m_3}{gcd\left(lcm\left(m_1,m_2\right),m_3\right)}=\frac{lcm\left(m_1,m_2,m_3\right)}{gcd\left(m_1,m_2,m_3\right)}$ is true for any positive integers $ m_1,m_2, m_3 $?

I have test many numbers looks it is actually true.

Comment: Consider $a=8$, $b=4$, and $c=2$.

Comment: You are right, thanks so much. I have missed a condtion, $gcd(m_1,m_2,m_3)=1$, they are setwise prime.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#Examples) is a nice way to reduce it to checking a specific truth function is a tautology. It also makes obvious why you need setwise primality.

Comment: This is a special case of the linked gcd $\times$ lcm law (put $\,a = {\rm lcm}(m_1,m_2),\ b = m_3),$ and use lcm associativity. $\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conjecture is indeed correct. I suppose you can prove the following:

$$1) \ \ ab = gcd(a,b)\cdot lcm(a,b)$$
$$2) \ \ lcm(a,b,c) = lcm(lcm(a,b), c)$$
These are standard results, you can look them up.

From (1) you get:

$$gcd(lcm(a,b),c) \cdot lcm(lcm(a,b),c) = lcm(a,b)\cdot c$$
or that
$$gcd(lcm(a,b),c) = \frac{lcm(a,b)\cdot c}{lcm(a,b,c)}$$
Now consider:
$$\frac{lcm(a,b)\cdot c}{gcd(lcm(a,b), c)}$$
Put the value you obtained already and the it becomes:
$$lcm(a,b,c)$$

Hence proving the proposition.

More generally,
$$\frac{lcm(a,b)\cdot c}{gcd(lcm(a,b),c)}=lcm(a,b,c)\ \ \ \ \ \forall a,b,c \in Z^+$$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).